# Merge two CSS boxes in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Hi i am beginner in HTML and CSS and bootstrap. I am having a problem in creating the following box.

[image]

And here is the site where i am implementing it

[usamamashkoor.com](http://usamamashkoor.com)

here is my html

```
<div class="no-margin col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-8 body-holder">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
         <img alt="" class="img-responsive" src="assets/images/arrow_up.png" class="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
         <div class="upper-body">
             <p>
                Departing from Omaha, NE, USA - 09-Sep-2015 5:40 PM
             </p>
         </div>
        <div class="lower-body text-right">
             <p>
                Arriving at Madison, NE, USA - 10-Sep-2015 12:30 PM
             </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
          <img alt="" class="img-responsive" src="assets/images/arrow_down.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

If you have better approach that would be better then kindly tell me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you mention the problem that you are facing currently? I guess you have already implemented the screenshot.

Comment: i want to add merger them as like they are in image with background colors but in my html and css they are not merging they are having space in between them you will see when you inpspect element them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be This will Help??

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td style="background-color:grey" rowspan=2>
    <div>
        <img alt="" class="img-responsive" src="assets/images/arrow_up.png" class="">               
    </div>
    </td>
    <td style="background-color:grey">
        <div class="upper-body">
            <p>
        Departing from Omaha, NE, USA - 09-Sep-2015 5:40 PM
            </p>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td style="background-color:white" rowspan=2>
        <div>
            <img alt="" class="img-responsive" src="assets/images/arrow_down.png">
            </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="background-color:white">
        <div class="lower-body text-right">
        <p>
        Arriving at Madison, NE, USA - 10-Sep-2015 12:30 PM
        </p>
        </div>
    </td>           
</tr>
</table>
```

And you can use some CSS to have some padding across table cells to make it look as per your requirement

Comment: Thanks i will try and let you know in 5 mins